# Subtract list within list with a same list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list as below:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Now I would like to subtract all the lists in A with B

```
B=[1,1,1]
```

to get the following result C:

```
C=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

I know I can use zip to do two list subtraction, but I cannot use it directly on list within list. How can I do the above subtraction? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
C = [[a-b for a, b in zip(sublist, B)] for sublist in A]
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
C = [[j-B[i] for i, j in enumerate(sublist)] for sublist in A]
```

Using 3rd party library NumPy, you can utilize broadcasting to output an array:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([1,1,1])

C = A - B

print(C)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`.

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B=[1,1,1]
C = [list(np.array(i) - np.array(B)) for i in A]
print(C)
```

Using `operator.sub`

```
from operator import sub
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B=[1,1,1]
C = [list(map(sub, i, B)) for i in A]
print(C)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]B=[1,1,1]
B=[1,1,1]
C=[list(map(operator.sub, i,B)) for i in A]
print C
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as code with a description of how/why it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach without the use of NUMPY -

```
for innerList in A:
    newInner = []
    for j in range(0, len(innerList)):
        newInner.append(innerList[j] - B[j])
    C.append(newInner)
```